# ADFS idpinitiatedsignon aspx redirect with SAML request as the parameter

Tags: c#, saml, adfs

I am having a case where I need to pass in an extra parameter as a querystring after the redirect happens with the SAML token

Here is my scenario

https://URL/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=A

https://URL/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=B

Both have been setup right in ADFS and they are working as expected but we are having a slight issue with the CSS

We would want the landing page to look different based on what they have selected to login

But I am not able to figure out since the landing page always looks like this

https://URL/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=<>

Not sure how I can identify whether this is coming from source A or B

Please help!

Comment: waiting for anyone to respond to this